# Flutter widget rebuilding when TextField widget clicked

Tags: dart, flutter

I'm sure this is a rookie error however I can't seem to figure this one out.
In the app below, when the textfield in the second route is clicked the keyboard opens and immediately closes. On closer investigation it seems that the widget is being rebuilt whenever it gets focus, causing the route to reset, making it impossible for the user to enter text.

When I remove the "key" from the form the problem doesn't occur. This isn't a long term fix as I need the "key" so I can validate the form.

Any ideas?

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';


void main() => runApp(MyApp());

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      title: 'My app',
      debugShowCheckedModeBanner: false,
      theme: ThemeData(
        primarySwatch: Colors.lightBlue,
        fontFamily: 'Nunito',
      ),
      home: LoginPage(),
    );
  }
}


class LoginPage extends StatefulWidget {

  @override
  LoginPageState createState() {
    return new LoginPageState();
  }
}

class LoginPageState extends State<LoginPage> {

  Widget build(BuildContext context) {

    final GlobalKey<ScaffoldState> _scaffoldKey = new GlobalKey<ScaffoldState>();

    final registerButton = Padding(
      padding: EdgeInsets.symmetric(vertical: 16.0),
      child: RaisedButton(
        shape: RoundedRectangleBorder(
          borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(24),
        ),
        onPressed: () {
          Navigator.push(
            context,
            MaterialPageRoute(builder: (context) => SecondPage()),
          );
        },
        child: Text('Register Now', style: TextStyle(color: Colors.white)),
      ),
    );

    // Now load the main login page
    return Scaffold(
      backgroundColor: Colors.white,
      key: _scaffoldKey,
      body: Center(
        child: ListView(
          shrinkWrap: true,
          children: <Widget>[
            registerButton,
          ],
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}


class SecondPage extends StatelessWidget {

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {

    final emailController =  TextEditingController();
    final _formKey = GlobalKey<FormState>();

    final email = TextFormField(
      keyboardType: TextInputType.emailAddress,
      controller: emailController,
      autofocus: false,
      decoration: InputDecoration(
        hintText: 'Email',
        contentPadding: EdgeInsets.fromLTRB(20.0, 10.0, 20.0, 10.0),
        border: OutlineInputBorder(borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(32.0)),
      ),
    );

    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: Text('Second page'),
      ),
      body: Center(
        child: Form(
          key: _formKey,
          child: email,
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: I have similar issue, as I debug the program, in my case Page Widget is triggered by Navigator.push and seems that Navigator.push is re-executed again the Page Widget creation everytime I tap the TextField. Have you tried to put breakpoint on Navigator.push?

Answer (score 20, accepted):

you have to declare **_formKey** as static outside of build method.

Comment: Thanks for your reply, the same behaviour happens when _formkey is declared outside the build method.

Comment: make it static.

Comment: Thank you that worked! Are you able to explain why declaring it as static made the difference?

Comment: i don't know much more about it. i faced same issue few days ago and at that time i found solution on github some where. i think flutter try to re declare formkey and it is creating confusion that's why may be.

Answer (score 15):

if your screen **depends** on **MediaQuery** or **at least** having **one** widget depenig on MediaQuery, the keyboard popup changes the size of your screen, which triggers mediaQuery and causing rebuilds...in this case avoid using mediaQuery, Instead get your dimensions using (sizer package) https://pub.dev/packages/sizer

Comment: This was my case.

Comment: Yep, MediaQuery is getting me... thanks!

Comment: Thanks  It solves unnecessary builds...

Answer (score 6):

When we click on `TextField` then `build()` method is called automatically by flutter so your all object is recreate which initialise within `build()` method.

That's why always create global variable which is used in `Form()` like :

```
final emailController =  TextEditingController();
final _formKey = GlobalKey<FormState>();
```

Comment: can you provide example on how to use the global variable  `_formKey` for TextField

Answer (score 2):

When you click to `TextField`, Flutter redeclare your `_formKey`. So it cause to rebuild your widget. You need to declare `_formKey` outside the `build` method so Flutter will not redeclare your variable.

Answer (score 0):

This strange behavoiur of media query when we click on textfield and keyBoard open media query rebulid one more same page in stack.

***MaterialApp(
useInheritedMediaQuery: true,)***

useInheritedMediaQuery to true.