# Why when use TextFormField inside bottom sheet, it rebuild widget?

Tags: android, flutter, dart

I have problem. when use TextFormField inside bottom sheet and click on TextFormField, it rebuild full widget from builder bottom sheet parameter to end.
I note that print "showBottomSheet" four times when click on and four time when back.

```
class ReturnRequestSearch extends StatefulWidget {
  const ReturnRequestSearch({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  State<ReturnRequestSearch> createState() => _ReturnRequestSearchState();
}

class _ReturnRequestSearchState extends State<ReturnRequestSearch> {

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    print('build button');
    return  IconButton(
      onPressed: (){
        showModalBottomSheet(
            context: context,
            shape: const RoundedRectangleBorder(
              // <-- SEE HERE
              borderRadius: BorderRadius.vertical(
                top: Radius.circular(25.0),
              ),
            ),
            isScrollControlled: true,
            backgroundColor: Colors.white,
            builder: (context) {
              print('showBottomSheet');
              return Padding(
                padding: const EdgeInsets.all(8.0),
                child: Padding(
                  padding: MediaQuery.of(context).viewInsets,
                  child: Column(
                    mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
                    crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.center,
                    mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.min,
                    children: [
                      TextField()

                    ],
                  ),
                ),
              );
            });
      },
      icon: const Icon(Icons.search),
    );
  }


}
```

Comment: It’s because of media query, refer this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55474562/flutter-widget-rebuilding-when-textfield-widget-clicked

Comment: I removed, but stile same error